# Nginx and Gunicorn 502

Tags: python, django, nginx, gunicorn

I am deploying an application to a server, but I seem to be misunderstanding some basic concepts here. The problem is that I am using gunicorn with port 8001

```
gunicorn myproj.wsgi:application --bind XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:8001
```

Nginx, however, is listening to port 8000, as you can see in the file /etc/nginx/sites-available/myproj:

```
server {
    listen 8000;
    server_name XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX;

    access_log off;

    location /static/ {
        root /opt/myproj;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8001;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        add_header P3p 'CP="ALL DSP COR PSAa PSDa OUR NOR ONL UNI COM NAV"';
    }
}
```

So, here is what happens:

When I access XXX.XXX.XXX.XXXX:8001, I get my page, but without any of the static files. I can access the static files by XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:8000/static/css/mycss.css. However, when I access XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:8000, I get a `502 - Bad Gateway` error.

What am I misunderstanding here? How can I access my page with the static files?

Comment: Can you access 127.0.0.1:8001? If not, bind Gunicorn to that host and port.

Comment: I ran a curl and got Connection refused

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is happening because you are binding gunicorn to your external ip, but nginx is forwarding to the localhost port. The point is that gunicorn should not be accessible to the outside at all; all requests should go through the nginx reverse proxy.

Bind gunicorn to 127.0.0.1:8001.

Comment: If I bind gunicorn to the local ip, with `gunicorn myproj.wsgi:application --bind 127.0.0.1:8001`, I get a `This webpage is not available
ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED` error when loading the page in any port

Comment: But you then mustn't go to :8001; you go to :8000, so that the page is served through nginx.

Answer (score 1):

The basic scheme when using application servers, like gunicorn is:

**[User's web browser] <-> [Web server(Nginx)] <-> [Application server(Gunicorn)]**

The web server usually listens on public IP address on port 80, and then forwards the connection to application server, serving as reverse proxy. If you run application server and web server on same host it's common to bind both to "localhost"(IP: 127.0.0.1) and same port, i.e. 8001 in your case. So try binding Gunicorn on 127.0.0.1:8001 as specified in your Nginx configuration.

Note: In case when two servers are running on one machine, it's usually worth connecting them via Unix sockets instead of network sockets for performance reasons.